# How to sort TBB concurrent_vector or concurrent_queue?

Tags: sorting, tbb, concurrent-queue, concurrent-vector

Now I have a solver in that I need to keep a set of self-defined data type objects in a concurrent_vector or queue. It has to be concurrent because the objects come from different threads.With this concurrent container, I hope to sort these objects, eliminate duplicates and send them back when other threads need them.

However, I know TBB offers concurrent_vector and concurrent_queue which can be read and written concurrently from different threads. But how to sort the objects inside a container? 
Does everyone know how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have some misunderstanding of TBB concurrent container. You can refer to [TBB wiki](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/faq/11)

*Do TBB concurrent containers use OS synchronization objects?*

- No, they don’t. TBB concurrent containers utilize TBB user-level synchronization primitives and atomic operations.

*Is it thread-safe to access and modify elements of `tbb::concurrent_vector` without locking?*

- No, you have to use locks explicitly.

Therefore, concurrent_vector does not support thread-safe multi-thread read and write. 
I hope this help.

Comment: :), Just fixed it. They changed the web site structure recently. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the producer threads should run concurrently with the consumer threads.
So if the elements would not need to be sorted and made unique a simple concurrent_queue would suffice.

If you only need to make them unique, you could use a `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` for that.

However, if you really want to have the elements sorted, you need something like a
concurrent_set (ordered) which is rather complicated and does not exist in tbb.
So if you really need to have those elements sorted, i would propose to use a simple lock which must be aquired for putting elements to your container (e.g. std::set) and for retrieving them out of it.

Answer (score 1):

concurrent_vector works with std::sort and both tbb & ppl ([in the sample pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/01/26/how-to-pick-your-parallel-sort.aspx)) offer parallel sorts that can be used with this.  A parallel version of std::unique would be even more useful for removing dupes, but you'd have to build your own.